# Handle mutiple routing concepts in Angular 6/7

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have a multipage-application with a single-page section.
Some routes have a hash:

/#/calendar, /#/profile

And some routes don't:
/pagexyz

I solved half of the problem: the pages that don't have a hash in the url get loaded directly without the router-outlet and the other pages get loaded with the router outlet. I controll the switching with ngIf.

The remaining problem is that the angular-router things it has to handle the current non-hash route an changes the location of the page to /#/.

Is there any way to stop the router from the root-component?
Can I have two router with different configuration (with and without hash)?

Thx for help.

Comment: Angular provides module concept. I suggest you to use modules instead of *ngIf for specific routes. it will gives you more control over routes. you will also get benefits in future.
With every single modules; you can have its own routes.

Comment: Agree with Hardik ,So basically your each component can have their own rotuer-outlet

Comment: thats also a possible way. Maybe I switch my concept to modules. But I found another solution with setting the option "initialNavigation" to false.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. As @Hardik (thx btw) mentioned I could use modules to seperate the "hash-part" of my application from the rest. But I've found a simple way by setting the initialNavigation-Config-Flag to false. It works like expected now.